# Spring mvc : Unit testing a controller with MockMultipartFIle and other form data

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I'm trying to unit test a controller which takes an request object of type `ArticleForm` and it contains a list of `MultipartFile`.

Here is the controller method that I'm trying to test.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute @Valid ArticleForm articleForm,
                BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
  ....
 }
```

Below is the Model attribute object `ArticleForm`

```
public class ArticleForm {
    private String id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String title;

    @NotEmpty
    private String description;

    private List<MultipartFile> images = Collections.emptyList();

  }
```

In my unit test, I want to submit 3 `MockMulitpartFile` objects as well as `title` and `description`

Here is what I have tried. The `title` and `description` gets populated but the `images` list is empty

```
@Test
public void adminController_saveArticleWithTitleAndDescription() throws Exception {

    final MockMultipartFile multipartFile1 = new MockMultipartFile("image1", "image1", "image/png", getResourceAsStream("/images/image1.png"));
    final MockMultipartFile multipartFile2 = new MockMultipartFile("image2", "image2", "image/png", getResourceAsStream("/images/image2.png"));
    final MockMultipartFile multipartFile3 = new MockMultipartFile("image3", "image3", "image/jpeg", getResourceAsStream("/images/image2.png"));

    mockMvc.perform(fileUpload("/admin/save")
            .file(multipartFile1)
            .file(multipartFile2)
            .file(multipartFile3)
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            .param("title", "Integration Testing")
            .param("description", "This is an integration test"))
            .andExpect(flash().attribute(FLASH_TYPE, is(FLASH_TYPE_SUCCESS)))
            .andExpect(flash().attribute(FLASH_MESSAGE, is(msgs.getMessage("controller.admin.save.success"))))
            .andExpect(status().isFound())
            .andExpect(view().name("redirect:/admin/add"));
}
```

How can I submit those 3 `MockMultipartFile` objects to the `images` list in the `ArticleForm` model attribute ?

Appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test is correct. Use "images" for the file name like below.

```
final MockMultipartFile multipartFile1 = new MockMultipartFile("images", "image1", "image/png", getResourceAsStream("/images/image1.png"));
final MockMultipartFile multipartFile2 = new MockMultipartFile("images", "image2", "image/png", getResourceAsStream("/images/image2.png"));
final MockMultipartFile multipartFile3 = new MockMultipartFile("images", "image3", "image/jpeg", getResourceAsStream("/images/image2.png"));
```